# Reflection for COM object

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have next Com object:

```
public interface ParagraphFormat2 : _IMsoDispObj
{
    [DispId(2)]
    MsoParagraphAlignment Alignment { get; set; }
    [DispId(1610743808)]
    object Application { get; }
    [DispId(3)]
    MsoBaselineAlignment BaselineAlignment { get; set; }
    [DispId(4)]
    BulletFormat2 Bullet { get; }
  }
```

I need to set Bullet property, so I am tiring to use reflection, but unsuccessful:
 - first try:

```
PropertyInfo prop = typeof(Microsoft.Office.Core.ParagraphFormat2)
                      .GetProperty("Bullet", BindingFlags.Public |
                                             BindingFlags.Instance |
                                             BindingFlags.GetProperty);

if (null != prop && prop.CanWrite)
{
    prop.SetValue(objParagraphFormat, bullet, null);
}
```

Second try:

```
typeof(Microsoft.Office.Core.ParagraphFormat2)
                    .GetField("Bullet", BindingFlags.PutDispProperty |
                                        BindingFlags.PutRefDispProperty)
                    .SetValue(objParagraphFormat, new object[] { bullet });
```

Any ideas how it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Marshall.PrtToStructure method
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4ca6d5z7(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Well 'ParagraphFormat2' is also read only, so I thing PrtToStructure doesn't helps here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the `Bullet` property, you use the `Bullet` property to obtain the `BulletFormat2` object, then set the properties of that object.

Like so:

```
objParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type = MsoBulletType.msoBulletUnnumbered;
objParagraphFormat.Bullet.Visible = MsoTriState.True;
```

It shouldn't be necessary to use reflection to do what you are doing.

Explanation: the `Bullet` object doesn't have an independent existence of its own, its only purpose is a convenient grouping for the various list and bullet related paragraph properties.

In other words, really these are all properties of the paragraph - the bullet object just exists to make things a bit tidier and more readable.